# Angular - Trouble getting single document from Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a list of users, which is a collection in Firestore, then the user will be able to click on a user and be redirected to a user profile page with the more data. I am able to display the data; however, I am getting a console error for every other document in the collection saying that the properties could not be found.

user-profile.ts:

```
 ngOnInit() {
//get user id from route
this.uid = this.route.snapshot.params['uid'];

//get user document reference from firestore using auth service
this.authService.getUserDocById(this.uid).get().then(doc =>{
    this.user = doc.data();
  }
);

if(this.uid == this.authService.getFirebaseUser().uid){
  this.isOwnProfile = true;
}
else{
  this.isOwnProfile = false;
 }
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
getUserDocById(uid: string)
  {
    var path = ('users/' + uid);
    return this.afs.doc(path).ref; 
  }
```

user-profile.component.html:

```
  <div class="imagewrapper">
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'isOwnImage' : isOwnProfile }" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + user.profileImageUrl + ')' }" class="profileImage"></div>
```

I am getting this consle error for however many users are in the collection, besides the one I am currently viewing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'profileImageUrl' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UserProfileComponent.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10853)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10250)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10491)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10433)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10256)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10491)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10454)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10251)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10491)
```

Comment: Please do console for this.user. And check what it contains.

Comment: As it states, `user` is undefined. This is most likely because the `ngStyle` is trying to access `user.profileImageUrl` before your service sets `user`.

Comment: when I log `this.user` to the console I get `[object Object]`, not `undefined`. On the profile that I click on I can see the profile Image. It seems like its trying to get the `profileImageUrl` for every single user in the collection for some reason

Comment: on that div use ngIf:  *ngIf="user" So, because of this it'll not try to resolve that property until service returns it. do console.log(this.user); after  doc.data(). You're wrting it in string comment thus it's showing [object object]

Comment: @Shantanu Adding the `*ngIf="user"` worked! Thank you so much :)